# How to parse a external JSON file with arrays with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, jquery-plugins

I am currently struggling with the issue of reading in a JSON file with javascript. 

I am not entirely sure if this is the correct format for a JSON file with arrays, but here is my JSON file.

```
  [
      {
       "passageNumber":"2.3.1",
       "title":"Inside and out: A bronze Athena and a Temple of Octavia",
        "preReading":"This paragraph appears to refer to what the excavators named Temple E...",
        "reading":"<span>Lorem</span> ipsum <span>dolor</span> sit amet, consectetur",
        "media":"<img src='img/TempleE-capital.jpg'>",
        "lon":"41.925",
        "lat":"-91.426"
       },
       {
        "passageNumber":"2.3.2",
        "title":"The Road to Lechaeum",
        "preReading":"<a href='http://google.com'>yipppie",
        "postReading":"",
        "reading":"blahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh.",
        "media":"<img src='img/templE-brick.jpg'>",
        "lon":"41.625",
        "lat":"-91.672"
       }
   ]
```

I ultimately would like to be able to read the JSON file (most likely with JQuery), and then select all of the information given a passage number.

Any help would be amazing.

Thank you!

**EDIT**
I am pulling this from an external JSON file. It needs to load in the JSON file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: Once you loaded the file with Ajax, just use `JSON.parse(theString)` to get a JS object.

Comment: you can check the validation of your JSON at https://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Answer (score 4):

Below is sample snippet how to read the JSON.

```js
var JSONDataFromExternalFile = '[{"passageNumber":"2.3.1","title":"Inside and out: A bronze Athena and a Temple of Octavia","preReading":"This paragraph appears to refer to what the excavators named Temple E...","reading":"<span>Lorem</span> ipsum <span>dolor</span> sit amet, consectetur","media":"<img src=\'img/TempleE-capital.jpg\'>","lon":"41.925","lat":"-91.426"},{"passageNumber":"2.3.2","title":"The Road to Lechaeum","preReading":"<a href=\'http://google.com\'>yipppie","postReading":"","reading":"blahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh.","media":"<img src=\'img/templE-brick.jpg\'>","lon":"41.625","lat":"-91.672"}]'

var data = JSON.parse(JSONDataFromExternalFile);

function getDetails(passageNumber){

  for(i in data){
    if (data[i].passageNumber == passageNumber)
      return data[i];
  }
  return false;
}

var details = getDetails("2.3.2");
alert("title > "+details.title);
alert("preReading > "+details.preReading);

var details = getDetails("2.3.1");
alert("title > "+details.title);
alert("preReading > "+details.preReading);
```

In your code it would probably look like this.

**UPDATE**

```
$.ajax({
     url: "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cgRivNixNK",
     type: "POST", //type:"GET"
     dataType: "JSON",
     success: function(data){
           console.log(data)
     }
})
```

OR

```
$.ajax({
     url: "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cgRivNixNK",
     type: "POST", //type:"GET"
     dataType: "JSON"
})
.done(function(data){
           console.log(data)
});
```

Comment: This is not using a JSON file rather using a javascript object _data_ to act like a JSON. I HAVE to pull it directly from an external JSON file.

Comment: external JSON doesnt really make any diff, also I have added how it would look with external JSON also. `$.ajax({...`

Comment: Sorry, I still do not understand.  What does the second snippet of code produce?

Comment: that is the AJAX call to fetch the external JSON file, where `url` is the address of external JSON file.

Comment: I am struggling more than i should at the moment. I have tried to read in an external JSON file have haven't had any luck. I am unsure what I am dong wrong.  I have messing around just to print out the contents of my JSON file and it is causing more frustration than anything else. Here is what I currently have, can you tell me what I am doing wrong? `$.ajax({
     url: "src/passages.json",
     type: "POST",
     dataType: "JSONP",
     done: function(data){
     var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
     console.log(data);
     }
})`

Comment: This answer is great! Do you know how I can get this data to show up on a linked html file rather than in the console?

Comment: use DOM API to put the content in html document.. something like `document.getElementById('IDOfElement').innerHTML = data[index].title`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that example is valid JSON.

You can read the file and work with the data by using [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getDetails(passageNumber, strJSON) {
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(strJSON);
    
    
    $.each(obj, function (key, value) {
        if (passageNumber == value.passageNumber) {
   
            result = value;
            return false;
        }
    });
    
    return result;
}


var strJSON = '[\
  {"passageNumber":"2.3.1",\
   "title":"Inside and out: A bronze Athena and a Temple of Octavia",\
    "preReading":"This paragraph appears to refer to what the excavators named Temple E...",\
    "reading":"<span>Lorem</span> ipsum <span>dolor</span> sit amet, consectetur",\
    "media":"<img src=\'img / TempleE - capital.jpg \'>",\
    "lon":"41.925",\
    "lat":"-91.426"},\
   {"passageNumber":"2.3.2",\
    "title":"The Road to Lechaeum",\
    "preReading":"<a href=\'http: //google.com\'>yipppie",\
  "postReading": "",\
  "reading": "blahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh.",\
  "media": "<img src=\'img/templE-brick.jpg\'>",\
  "lon": "41.625",\
  "lat": "-91.672"\
}\
]';


var result = getDetails("2.3.1", strJSON);
if(result != null) {
    alert(result.passageNumber);
    alert(result.title);
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It's a very valid format and represents array of objects.

To find the information by passage number, the following function will help you:

```
function getDetails(passageNumber, strJSON) {
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(strJSON);


    $.each(obj, function (key, value) {
        if (passageNumber == value.passageNumber) {

            result = value;
            return false;
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

Just pass your passage number and the json text to the function and it will return you the corresponding information mapped to that particular passage number. I have attached a code snippet too.

It will be a good idea to preprocess the data to store as key value pairs of passage numbers and corresponding data provided passage numbers are unique and calls to fetch data are high.